# What happened on Aug 7? Massive unaccepts

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, unaccepted-answer

I was looking through my reputation history on Stack Overflow and was surprised to see that I lost a whopping 558 points on August 7th! Expanding the view I see a whole bunch of questions apparently marked as unaccepted at exactly 03:00. Visiting each question shows that my answers on them are still accepted, however.

[image: reputation history]

Am I the victim of a bug? Is this a known issue?

Comment: Wow, that's like Jon Skeet in red instead of green...

Comment: This is unacceptable  (Couldn't resist).

Comment: Looks like a bug.

Comment: Have you tried triggering a rep recalc?

Comment: @nhahtdh, how do I do that?

Comment: @friedo: [/reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) - button at the bottom

Comment: @animuson: As far as I know the recalc does only change the number, not the history.

Comment: @nhahtdh, still looks the same after recalc.

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby: It's worth a try. It affected the history before, but nowadays with reputation being automatically updated for removals, it tends to be that the glitches that show up in the history don't always get fixed by recalcs anymore.

Comment: @Mysticial Are we dealing with Bizarro-Skeet here?

Comment: @Bart Unless it's rate-limited, someone *could* technically pull a stunt like that on Jon Skeet. Ask a bunch of questions that bait him to answer. Give him the accept each time. Then on a different day, unaccept them all at once.

Comment: @Mysticial Ah, but the answers aren't really unaccepted ;) Check OP's [rep tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20745/friedo?tab=reputation) and click on the answers reported as unaccepted...

Comment: @YannisRizos I know. I'm just saying that if someone wanted to make a massive list of unaccepts show up on Jon Skeet's profile (or any active user's profile) that's how you'd could do it.

Comment: @Mysticial But you'd have to re-accept for the answers to continue showing as accepted, and there's no trace of that in OP's rep tab.

Comment: @YannisRizos You reaccept them the next UTC day.

Comment: @Mysticial But that would have to show up as an event in the rep tab, wouldn't it? Anyway, hypotheticals. Fun glitch though.

Comment: @Bart It would, but you can still troll someone like that if you did it repeatedly. Now I should get some sleep before I spit out anymore nonsense...

Comment: Now we know whom to roll up into one big sockball.

Comment: We are looking for the cause of this now.  Don't worry, we have all the data to restore your accepts; just trying to figure out what happened.

Comment: Well, it gave you over 300 rep here on Meta - good start! ;)

Comment: Heh - I was just thinking that this question got me more upvotes than almost all of my "real" questions on SO.

Comment: It was the repocalypse! All shall perish!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

We have a scheduled process that does some cleanup around accepted answers, ensuring that no answer has more than one active accepted answer vote.  Before this incident, it had never found any problems.

For a few days, our [index optimization script](http://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) ran at the same time as this daily job, and a pitfall of running certain queries in NOLOCK means phantom data could appear.

The index optimization job was moved to a much earlier time weeks ago, so this should not happen again.

49 accepted answers (with yours being the bulk) have been repaired and your reputation should be back to normal.

Comment: Good job hunting this process down! Bet you found it cowering in a dark corner? :)

Comment: Yeah, perfect storms are never fun to track down - kudos go to [Nick Craver](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) for the insight.  We're looking at changing the connection behavior for these scheduled routes to further prevent these mishaps.

Comment: Cheers! Nick is really a nice person to let you collect rep on his insights.. :D

Comment: At dba.se: [is NOLOCK always bad?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10655/is-nolock-always-bad)

Comment: @ypercube - It's worth noting that the discussion between "reports" and "high scale website with millions of queries/updates a day" is a very different one with regards to NOLOCK :)

Comment: @Nick I do not disagree but the question was not about reports only but `NOLOCK` in general.

Comment: @ypercube - It was asked that way for sure...but looking at the answers it was discussed/answered from that point of view (where data accuracy is paramount).  When you throw exact accuracy out the window (since it's changing all the time), the answers/reasoning would be very different.  It would be interesting to ask that question from Stack Overflow's point of view and see what people think :)

Comment: @Nick: Rewreading those answers, yes, you are absolutely right. Also, such a question would be very interesting, indeed. The details of the scheduled process and the index optimization script as well.

Comment: An amusing aspect: SQL DBMS' excuse for continued existence, in some minds, is ACID, but so frequently ACID gets neutralized to get back performance. Perhaps you'd just be happier with Cassandra:-)?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and for repairing my tarnished reputation. :)

Comment: @Rosinante: Sure, if you don't mind losing the *relational* part.

Comment: What's an "active accepted answer vote?"

Comment: @Purmou you can click the accepted answer button multiple times on an answer, toggling the accepted answer state.  We store every vote you make, only soft-deleting older votes when you change your mind. An "active" vote is simply one that hasn't been deleted (i.e. its `DeletionDate` is null).

Comment: @Purmou so there should only be one "active" accepted answer vote on any of a question's answers at any time - preventing duplicates (due to client-server latency) is what this scheduled task aims to accomplish.

Comment: That's some nice detective work there, kudos!

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Wondering if a unique constraint would be better ;-)